# How to correctly create method accepting list of objects

Tags: java, list, generics

Hi I would like to create method which accepts list of Object something like this:

```java
public static String formatList(List<Object> listToFormat,int indentationSize){
        String indentation = Stream.generate(()->"\t").limit(indentationSize).collect(Collectors.joining());
        String newIndentedLine = "\n"+indentation;
        return newIndentedLine+listToFormat.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(newIndentedLine));
    }
```

but when I try to do something like this:

```java
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
...
Formater.formatList(cars);
```

it is not allowed.

Comment: Could you try `public static <T> String formatList(List<T> listToFormat,int indentationSize){`  to accept objects instead?

Comment: It is working!!! Thanks! Could you please add it as answer so I can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't allow this because a `List<Car>` is not a `List<Object>` even though a `Car` is an `Object`.

It's not necessary to declare a type parameter, because we don't care what the type actually is.  Every reference type descends from `Object` which has a `toString` method, so we can just replace `List<Object>` with `List<?>`:

```
public static String formatList(List<?> listToFormat, int indentationSize) {
```

Comment: What is difference between your answer and the answer from @Alias? Both works ...

Comment: Yes, both answers work, but I offered a (slightly) less complicated solution.

Answer (score 1):

You use `public static <T> String formatList(List<T> listToFormat,int indentationSize){` to accept objects instead.

#### Code:

```
public static <T> String formatList(List<T> listToFormat,int indentationSize){
        String indentation = Stream.generate(()->"\t").limit(indentationSize).collect(Collectors.joining());
        String newIndentedLine = "\n"+indentation;
        return newIndentedLine+listToFormat.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(newIndentedLine));
    }
```